# Copy previous words before specific word in string

Tags: vba, excel

I have a text file, its look like...

```
Blade Runner 2049 http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1856101

Kingsman: The Golden Circle http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4649466

The Crucifixion http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4181782/
```

I have code that finds all the lines "http://www.imdb.com/title" in a text file and copies the previous word (movie name) before"http://www.imdb.com/title"and paste them into Excel cells.

```
Sub GetText()
Dim fName As String, Word1 As String, Word2 As String, i As Long, s As String, st As String
fName = "C:\Test\test1.txt"
st = "http://www.imdb.com/title"
Open fName For Input As #1
   Do Until EOF(1)
      Word1 = Word2
      Input #1, Word2
      If (Word2 = st & ">") Or (Word2 Like st & "/*") Then
          If Trim$(Word1) <> "" Then i = i + 1: Cells(i, 1) = Word1
      ElseIf Word2 Like "* " & st & "/*" Then
          Word1 = Trim$(Split(Word2)(1))
          If Trim$(Word1) <> "" Then i = i + 1: Cells(i, 1) = Word1
      End If
   Loop
Close #1
End Sub
```

But this code paste only first word from movie name. What do I need to change to paste the full movie name?

Comment: `Split(Word2)(1)` should be `Split(Word2, st)(0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple way to do this would be by using the [`Split()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx).

```
Sub Test()

    Dim OrigStr$, YourMovie$
    OrigStr = "Kingsman: The Golden Circle http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4649466"

    YourMovie = Split(OrigStr, " http:")(0)
    MsgBox YourMovie

End Sub
```

The `(0)` at the end of the function states you want the entire string *prior* to your found word. On the contrary, using `(1)` means you want the string after the first iteration of your found word (" http:"), `(2)` for the string after the 2nd iteration of that work, etc.

Please be aware: You can still use `Split()` without using `(i)`, (`Split()`, not `Split()(i)`). When you use this method, you are actually returning the value into an array as opposed to a string.

Here is another example of the above if you were to return the value to an array:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim OrigStr$, OrigStrArr$(), YourMovie$
    OrigStr = "Kingsman: The Golden Circle http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4649466"

    OrigStrArr = Split(OrigStr, " http:")
    YourMovie = OrigStrArr(0)
    MsgBox YourMovie

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can just open the file in Excel and remove the URL parts (not tested):

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\Test\test1.txt"
Cells.Replace " http://www.imdb.com/title/*", "", xlPart
```

Similarly, to get only the URL:

```
Cells.Replace "* http://www.imdb.com/title/", "http://www.imdb.com/title/", xlPart
```

Answer (score 1):

I would parse it just like in the worksheet:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim st As String, s As String, MovieName As String

    st = "http://www.imdb.com/title"
    s = "Blade Runner 2049 http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1856101"
    MovieName = ""

    If InStr(1, s, st) > 0 Then
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            MovieName = Left(s, .Find(st, s) - 1)
        End With
    End If
    MsgBox MovieName
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This one uses regular expressions:

```
Sub GetText()
Dim fName As String
Dim i As Long
Dim FileContents As String
Dim collMatches As Collection
fName = "C:\Test\test1.txt"
Open fName For Input As #1
FileContents = Input(LOF(1), 1)
Close 1

Set collMatches = GetRegexMatches(FileContents, "^.*(?=http)")
Debug.Print collMatches.Count
For i = 1 To collMatches.Count
   Cells(i, 1) = collMatches(i)
Next i
End Sub

Function GetRegexMatches(inputstring As String, SearchPattern As String, _
                         Optional boolIgnoreCase As Boolean = True, Optional boolGlobal As Boolean = True, Optional boolMultiline As Boolean = True, _
                         Optional UniqueMatches As Boolean = False) As Collection
Dim Regex As Object
Dim rgxMatch As Object
Dim rgxMatches As Object
Dim collMatches As Collection
Dim collUniqueMatches As Collection

Set Regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With Regex
    'search for any integer matches
    '"\d+" is the same as "[0-9]+"
    .Pattern = SearchPattern
    .IgnoreCase = boolIgnoreCase
    'Find all matches, not just the first
    .Global = boolGlobal
    '^ and $ work per-line, not just at begin and end of file
    .MultiLine = boolMultiline
    'built-in test for matches
    Set collMatches = New Collection
    Set collUniqueMatches = New Collection
    If .test(inputstring) Then
        'if matches, create a collection of them
        Set rgxMatches = .Execute(inputstring)
        For Each rgxMatch In rgxMatches
            collMatches.Add rgxMatch
            On Error Resume Next
            collUniqueMatches.Add rgxMatch, rgxMatch
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next rgxMatch
    End If
End With

If UniqueMatches Then
    Set GetRegexMatches = collUniqueMatches
Else
    Set GetRegexMatches = collMatches
End If

Set Regex = Nothing

End Function
```